# How to handle Null check for trim () & toLowerCase() in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have an input field in Angular 7 for that i use trim () and toLowerCase() the logic works but some times in console it shows .trim() and toLowerCase() of undefined how to handle this errors please help.

```
             <input
             oninput="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase()"
             (blur)="supplierInfo.name = supplierInfo.name.trim()"
             [(ngModel)]="supplierInfo.name" 
              />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do null/undefined checks by using safe navigation operator ( ? )

For example:

```
(blur)="supplierInfo?.name = supplierInfo?.name?.trim()"
```

Adding the same for this.value

```
oninput="this.value = this.value?.toLowerCase()" - In this case, it the new value is null/undefined - then it will retain the same
oninput="this.value = this.value?.toLowerCase() || ''" - Will update the string to a blank string
```

Comment: how to do for this one   oninput="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase()"

Comment: Depends what you want. You can use this.value = this.value?.toLowerCase(). This will set the value to undefined. And you can also set it to blank using this.value = this.value?.toLowerCase() || ''

Comment: Ho to provide null check for this one {{ itemFornew.location.addressLine2 }}